# Global keybindings don't work in 'smex'

Tags: ido, flx-ido

I've installed [`smex`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Smex) through MELPA as a replacement for the default <kbd>M-x</kbd> (`execute-extended-command`). The issue is that in `smex`, certain global keybindings don't work. For instance, <kbd>C-h</kbd> should work as backspace, yet in `smex` it's still bound to default `help`.

```lisp
(global-set-key (kbd "C-h") 'delete-backward-char)
```

Any idea why the above `global-set-key` might not work in `smex`, while it does elsewhere (in minibuffer, eshell, etc.)?

### Addendum to Jesse's answer

When using `ido-vertical-mode` one should also rebind `M-p`:

```lisp
(defun ido-vertical-define-keys ()
(define-key ido-completion-map (kbd "C-n") 'ido-next-match)
(define-key ido-completion-map (kbd "C-p") 'ido-prev-match)
(define-key ido-completion-map (kbd "M-p") 'previous-history-element))
```

Comment: IMO `C-h` is way more valuable as a help binding (especially `C-h v`, `C-h f` and `C-h k`/`C-h c`) unless you prefer to use `F1` instead.

Comment: @kaushalmodi, but isn't backspace somewhat out of reach? Or do you use some other binding for `delete-backward-char` altogether?

Comment: I've got used to `DEL` (backspace) and `C-DEL`; don't find it that inconvenient. Probably I use `C-d` and `M-d` equally or more.

Comment: About the edit you made related to `ido-vertical-mode`.. note that you then  are losing the `C-p` and `C-n` bindings which are more intuitive for up/down navigation in `ido-vertical-mode`. You should copy that whole function to your emacs config and then only edit the bindings you care about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also had this problem and couldn't fix. My workaround was overriding the smex keybindings function:

```el
(defun smex-prepare-ido-bindings ()
  (define-key ido-completion-map (kbd "TAB") #'minibuffer-complete)
  (define-key ido-completion-map (kbd "M-p") #'previous-history-element)
  (define-key ido-completion-map (kbd "M-.") #'smex-find-function)
  (define-key ido-completion-map (kbd "C-h") #'delete-backward-char)
  (define-key ido-completion-map (kbd "C-a") #'move-beginning-of-line))
```

Comment: Nice. There's only one snag: `M-p` doesn't get defined and is still bound to "`ido-toggle-prefix`, which is an interactive compiled Lisp function in `ido.el'."

Comment: @courteous I bet you have `ido-vertical` installed too because that sets `M-p` binding to `ido-toggle-prefix` (as it needs to use the original binding of `ido-toggle-prefix`.. `C-p` for `ido-prev-match` (ido match navigation)). To change that, you will need to override the `ido-vertical-define-keys` function in the same fashion as this solution for overriding bindings set by smex.

Comment: @kaushalmodi, `ido-vertical` it is. That fixed the `M-p` as well. Regarding your edit of Jesse's answer: what difference do hashtags `#` make? Also, how did you go about finding that it is `ido-vertical-define-keys` that must be overridden?

Comment: @courteous My approach to find such bindings is probably unconventional but I simply did `ag 'p.*ido-toggle-prefix'` in my `~/.emacs.d` and emacs source code `lisp/` directories... and [about the *sharp-quotes*](http://endlessparentheses.com/get-in-the-habit-of-using-sharp-quote.html). *ag is like grep but faster.*

Comment: How could I convert `C-s` to `C-n` and `C-r` to `C-p` ?

Answer (score 0):

I have used [eval-after-load](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2736153/2402577). I don't konw but @Jesse's solution was not changed the keybindings.

> Code wrapped in `eval-after-load` will be executed only once. , so it
> is typically used to perform `one-time` setup such as setting default
> global values and behaviour.

---

```
(setq smex-save-file "~/.emacs.d/settings/smex-items")
(global-set-key (kbd "M-x") 'smex)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-X") 'smex-major-mode-commands)

(eval-after-load 'smex
  `(defun smex-prepare-ido-bindings ()
     (define-key ido-completion-map (kbd "TAB") 'minibuffer-complete)
     (define-key ido-completion-map (kbd "C-,") 'smex-describe-function)
     (define-key ido-completion-map (kbd "C-w") 'smex-where-is)
     (define-key ido-completion-map (kbd "C-.") 'smex-find-function)
     (define-key ido-completion-map (kbd "C-a") 'move-beginning-of-line)
     (define-key ido-completion-map (kbd "C-p") 'previous-history-element)
     ))
```